# Swift: Use function in a ViewController from a TableViewController

Tags: swift, function, settings, swift2, avaudioplayer

I am trying to call a function from a `UITableViewController` in my `UIViewController`. *`ViewController`* is where the sound will be played, but I would like to change that sound from the *`SettingsView`* by selecting a Table Cell.

ViewController: `UIViewController`

```
 import UIKit
 import AVFoundation

 class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func playSound(sender: UIButton) {

            playAudio() //Starting Audio

        }
```

SettingsView: `UITableViewController`

```
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

func playAudio(audioName: String ) {
    if let audioURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(audioName, withExtension: "mp3") {
             audioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: audioURL)
             audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
             audioPlayer.play()
             audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
        } 
       //Standard Fan is Table Cell
        if standardFan.accessoryType == .Checkmark {
            playAudio("fanpost")
            print("Standard")
        } 
       //Alternate Fan is a Table Cell
        if alternateFan.accessoryType == .Checkmark {
            playAudio("AlternateFan")
            print("Alternate")
        } 
       //White Fan is a Table Cell
        if whiteFan.accessoryType == .Checkmark {
            playAudio("WhiteNoise")
            print("White")
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use `NSNotificationCenter` for this.

Comment: Thanks, I looked into it and ended up fixing my problem